# MWFeedParser stringByReplacingXmlEntities memory leak

Tags: iphone

```
 NSURL *xmlUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.xml-document.xml"];
 NSString *converted = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlUrl encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:nil];

 converted = [converted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
 converted = [converted stringByDecodingXMLEntities];
```

The last line takes up 98.3% of the memory in Instruments > Leaks.

And it's smashing my Log window with:

```
__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x6d10ba0 of class UIView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

Why? I think that method has worked good before...

Comment: For starters you are leaking the first string - you own it but immediately overwrite it with a new one in the next line. Consider not using auto-released and possibly mutable strings if the document is big. Are you doing this in a separate thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling I found that it has to be because of these methods:

```
     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(load) withObject:loadingIndicator];
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getEvents) withObject:nil];
```

So I've tried allocating an NSAutoReleasePool and the release it after the work is done in the methods.

Now i receive **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** message.

This did *not* happended before I decided to run those methods in the background. So what's the problem here?

Comment: This was because I ran the creation of my UITableView in another thread than the thread I ran to get the datasource...